# appengine python NDB sort order has no effect

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, webapp2

I try to get the last modified entries using these kind of models in model.py:

```
class Example(ndb.Model):
    ....
    modified = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

The query code:

```
for each in ['Example', '...'] 
    model_class = webapp2.import_string('model.%s' % each)
    q = model_class.query()
    q.order(-model_class.modified)
    last_modified_entity = q.get()  # does not sort the entities
```

I also tried:

```
for each in ['Example', '...'] 
    model_class = webapp2.import_string('model.%s' % each)
    q = model_class.query()
    sort_prop = ndb.GenericProperty('modified')
    q.order(-sort_prop)
    last_modified_entity = q.get()  # does not sort the entities
```

Comment: `.get()` only returns one entity.  Are you expecting more?  Is it returning the most recent entity?

Comment: Yes, but it does not.

Comment: change `.get()` to `.fetch()` and see what it returns

Comment: fetch returns all entities and not in reverse order.

Comment: Does each entity have a `modified` property?

Comment: try: `q.order(model_class.modified)` to see if sorts ascending.  Try: `sort_prop = model_class.modified  q.order(-sort_prop)` to see if it is a bug with the `-` operator.

Comment: This very strange. I imported the model and tried using q.order(-Example.modified). And still the order failed.

Comment: Look at my answer below. `q.order(-sort_prop)` does not change the value of `q`. Instead, it returns a new Query object with that sort order on it, and q remains unsorted.

Comment: And also used: q.order(Example.modified) which also failed ordering the entities.

Comment: By the way. This query is tested in production. So what is wrong here with the entities.

Comment: Brendan's answer is right: q is immutable, it remains unsorted unless you create it already sorted: `q = model_class.query().order(-sort_prop)`

Comment: YES, solved. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `.order()` on a Query object does NOT alter the Query object. It returns a new Query object with that order on it, but does not alter the original Query object. From [NDB Queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries) (emphasis mine):

> Instead of specifying an entire query filter in a single expression,
>   you may find it more convenient to build it up in steps: for example:
>
> ```
> query1 = Account.query()  # Retrieve all Account entitites
> query2 = query1.filter(Account.userid >= 40)  # Filter on userid >= 40
> query3 = query2.filter(Account.userid < 50)  # Filter on userid < 50 too
> ```
>
> `query3` is equivalent to the `query` variable from the previous
>   example. **Note that query objects are immutable**, so the
>   construction of `query2` does not affect `query1` and the construction
>   of `query3` does not affect `query1` or `query2`.

Example from the remote api shell:

```
>>>> from models.notification import Notification
>>>> query = Notification.query()
>>>> query
Query(kind='Notification')
>>>>
>>>> # this returns a new ordered query
>>>> query.order(Notification.created_on)
Query(kind='Notification', orders=...)
>>>> 
>>>> # but it does not alter the original query
>>>> query
Query(kind='Notification')
>>>>
>>>> # this is how you get the ordered query in a variable
>>>> ordered_query = query.order(Notification.created_on)
>>>> ordered_query
Query(kind='Notification', orders=...)
>>>> query
Query(kind='Notification')
```

So change your code to use this instead:

```
q = q.order(-sort_prop)
```